# Conflicting Django URL's

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I have been chopping away at this for a few days with no clue as to why its not working.  I have two views, one to list tools and one to list parts.  I also have the list and detail URL's for both.  Both list views work and the tool detail view works, but when I click on a part item to see the detail, the correct url appears in the browser, but I get an error shown in the screenshot below, which as you can see is trying to use the tool_detail view. Thank you for looking.

[image]

Here is my code for review:

**url:**

```
from .views import tool_list, part_list, tool_detail, part_detail

urlpatterns = [

    url(r'^products/tools/$', tool_list, name='tool_list'),
    url(r'^products/(?P<category>[^\.]+)/(?P<slug>[^\.]+)/$', tool_detail, name='tool_detail'),

    url(r'^products/parts/$', part_list, name='part_list'),
    url(r'^products/(?P<category>[^\.]+)/(?P<slug>[^\.]+)/$', part_detail, name='part_detail'),

]
```

**view:**

```
def tool_list(request):
    tools = Tool.objects.prefetch_related('uploads').all()
    return render(request, 'tool_list.html', {'tools': tools})


def tool_detail(request, **kwargs):
    tool = get_object_or_404(Tool, slug=kwargs.get('slug'))
    return render(request, 'tool_detail.html', {'tool': tool})


def part_list(request):
    parts = Part.objects.prefetch_related('uploads').all()
    return render(request, 'part_list.html', {'parts': parts})


def part_detail(request, **kwargs):
    part = get_object_or_404(Part, slug=kwargs.get('slug'))
    return render(request, 'part_detail.html', {'part': part})
```

**models**

```
class Part(Timestamp):
    model_number = models.ForeignKey(ModelNumber, related_name='part_model_number')
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, related_name='part_category')
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    slug = models.SlugField(help_text="slug-title-should-be-like-this")
    ...

class Tool(Timestamp):
    model_number = models.ForeignKey(ModelNumber, related_name='tool_model_number')
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    slug = models.SlugField(help_text="slug-title-should-be-like-this")
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, related_name='tool_category')
    ...
```

Comment: Did you see the second and fourth URL patterns?

Comment: Not sure what you mean...yes, I have seen them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first url pattern that matches is what Django will use to dispatch to a view. The 2nd url matches, so it's using the `tool_detail` view.

Comment: Ok, then I am confused on how to setup my views.  The URL's are not called based on the name?

Comment: I was able to fix it by changing my detail url paths to `...products/tools/(?P<category>[^\.]+)/...` and `...products/parts/(?P<category>[^\.]+)/...`

Comment: Excellent. That was going to be my next suggestion, but you beat me to it